# Is there a way to allow `<?php`  and `<?=` open tag but not `<?`?

Tags: php, php.ini

In PHP I would like to be able to use the `<?=` open tag (which is similar in effect to `<?php echo`) but I would also like to disallow the use of the short open tag for any other use than quickly `echo` stuff.

Is that possible? If it is, how could I achive this? I tried searching serverfault and Google and nothing came up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the php.ini configuration wouldn't let you do that out of the box.

You *could* modify the PHP source (depending on your knowledge of C), but that'd made upgrading evermore annoying in the future as you'd have to patch every version.

Comment: I know C but I'm not that motivated ^^. I guess I'll simply stop using `<?=`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wait until [5.4 is released](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=311260).  (Shamelessly copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use/6064813#6064813))

If you build PHP yourself, you should be able to make the change to `zend_language_scanner.l` [like so](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l?r1=311101&r2=311260&pathrev=311260).  I suspect the file should be there in 5.3.x